# invoking R from terminal

Tags: r, build

I have installed R in :

```
/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/bin
```

by building from source. R was downloaded in a folder and I used the following commands one after the other:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-R-shlib --enable-memory-profiling --with-tcltk=no
make
make check
make install
```

When I type `./R` here I can start R. How can I start `R` from anywhere in the terminal? Do I have to setup something in the bash_profile?

Previously, I could invoke R from anywhere in the terminal by typing `R`.

Comment: You need to export the path in your `.bash_profile`. Add this to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks! It works. If you can put it as an answer, I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the path in your `.bash_profile`, i.e., add this line to the file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/bin:$PATH
```